# push many many device ios with php apn

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I have to push notification to user' iOS devices using PHP APN lib.

I can push many devices ~ < 200 device

With ~ 500000 devices, how can I push with real time or the same (about 1 hour)?

I am going to use Gearmand with five threads that can push five notifications simultaneously?
==> but seem the notifications don't deliver all to user devices

I want to push in this site http://akatorrent.com

Can you tell me some approaches that you used to complete that job

Thank in advanced

Comment: In addition to threading you can send the push in chunks rather then bulk. look into sending in bacthes for example by 5000 at the time

Comment: Can you explain more @meda